# APK Expansion File updating imported Google libs

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

I'm using the APK expansion file in my application.
Firstly I downloaded these packages with the SDK Manager:

- Google Play Licensing Library package
- Google Play APK Expansion Library package

Then I added following 3 libs to my project:

- Google Play Downloader Library
- Google Play Market Licensing
- Google Play Zip File

[image: Project structure]

This was 1 year ago and I noticed that there was an update in this time for the zip file lib. But when I look in the directory /extras/google/... it is still the old version of the libs. I was assuming that the SDK Manager would automatically update them.

So my question is how can we update the imported libs?

Answer (score 0):

This code is now distributed via Github at https://github.com/google/play-licensing.

Embarassingly [the docs here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up#download-lvl) haven't been updated yet.